# Specifying local directory with WGET

Tags: download, directory, local, wget

I have a question regarding wget which I can't seem to figure out.

I am using the following command to download the whole content of my FTP server (which works fine)

```
wget -m -P c:\ ftp://user:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The problem is that this creates a folder in c:\ called 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' and places the whole FTP server content in this directory.

I do not wish for it to create this directory and just put the whole FTP directory structure directly in c:\

How can I specify this with wget?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-nH (--no-host-directories)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-P prefix
--directory-prefix=prefix
Set directory prefix to prefix. The directory prefix is the directory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree. The default is . (the current directory)
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Comment: Hi cggaurav, Thank you for your response.

Yes, I have read this but I still can't get it to stop creating a folder with the IP address. 

I would like it to download the FTP directory directly into the root of C:\